# iOS - Change width in iFrame tag in HTML

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, uiwebview

I am loading `UIWebView` with a string request. In my html string, I have `iframe` tag, in which it's width value is much greater than expected. How I can change that value?

My html string -

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
body {font-family:"Helvetica"; font-size: 18;} img {max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: 100%};
</style> 
</head> 
<body><p><span style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.6em;">***Some Text***.</span></p>

<p>***Some Text***.</p>

<p><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.some-domain.com/embed/mwOFWJUOpv8" width="600"></iframe></p></body>
```

As you can see, the **width=600** in `iframe` tag, which is causing problem in iPhone. How I can change that?

I have managed images by below code, I want to manage `iframe`.

Code so far implemented -

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                          "<head> \n"
                          "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                         "body {font-family:\"%@\"; font-size: %@;} img {max-width: 100%%; width: 100%%; height: 100%%};\n"
                          "</style> \n"
                          "</head> \n"
                          "<body>%@</body> \n"
                         "</html>", @"Helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:iWebViwFontSize], strHtml];
webViwNewsDescription loadHTMLString:str baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using @media and target screen width lower than X px . For instance 700 px, and add this in the CSS:

```
.frame {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Edit the (0.5) value to suit your needs. Than this will scale down the content in the iframe. I have not tested this via an iPhone, but it should work.

HTML:

```
<iframe class="frame"
```

edit:

Add this to your CSS file.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .frame {
        width:400px; /*or whatever width you'd like*/
        /*Here you can scale down the content in the iframe if it is too wide for the iframe*/
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
}
```

PS: If you don't know CSS well, this I add just to help you out:

In the **ordinary** css, add :

```
.iframe{width:600px;}
```

Then the width will be 600 px for all screens, but for screens less than 700 px the other CSS will do the trick.